# React : CKEditor5 Link popup not showing neither in bootstrap 5 modal nor rsuite library modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

React : CKEditor5 Link popup not showing neither in bootstrap 5 modal nor rsuite library modal

any approach to fix the issue

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the style of the componenet

```
:root {
    --ck-z-default: 10555 !important;
    --ck-z-modal: calc(var(--ck-z-default) + 10555) !important;

}
```